# Only white pieces allowed to move in chessboard.js

Tags: javascript, chessboard.js

Is there a way to configure chessboard.js so that only the white pieces can be moved by the user?

Answer (score 3):

Pretty sure the example can be adapted quite easily:

```
http://chessboardjs.com/examples#4002
```

Adapted code:

```
var onDragStart = function(source, piece, position, orientation) {  
    // if it's not white, don't allow drag
    if (piece.search(/^w/) === -1) ||
        return false;
    }
};

var cfg = {
  draggable: true,
  position: 'start',
  onDragStart: onDragStart
};
var board = ChessBoard('board', cfg);
```

Or just use the example in the documentation as-is, but don't change the orientation of the board.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still relevant 3 years later but you could try something like this:

```
if (piece.search(/^w/) === -1) {
     cfg.draggable = false;
}
```

I used something similar in my chess puzzle web page to stop all pieces movement when the puzzle is over and it works actually quite well.